# Points of the point cloud lying on 3D convex hull mesh

Tags: python, computational-geometry, mesh, point-clouds, open3d

Is there a way to list all the points that lie on the convex hull (it is a 3d mesh) that is computed using the method `compute_convex_hull` of Open3D. I want to do further processing on the points that specifically lie on the the mesh that is the output of `compute_convex_hull`. The point cloud input and the output hull are in 3D space. So, any help on achieving this in Open3D? If not, are there any other geometry processing library that can help me achieve this?

Comment: Isn't there a method to list the points of a mesh ?

Comment: Yes. But I want points in the original point cloud that lie on the convex hull. Not the vertices of the convex hull.

Comment: I am afraid that you will have to enumerate the hull vertices and find the nearest neighbors in the original mesh.

Comment: I guess I have no other choice.

Comment: But why do you need the original vertices ? Is there extra information attached ?

Comment: Yes. Original points represents the walls, ceiling and floor of the scene. That is what I need.

Comment: Er, points are points...